# How can I determine if an Iterable will be empty or not after iterating in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, iterator, generator, iterable

How can I differentiate between iterables that become empty after iteration and those that don't, in TypeScript?

```js
type ReusableIterable<T> = Iterable<T> // ?

function iterate(iterable: ReusableIterable<any>) {
    // Do something with iterable
    console.log(Array.from(iterable))
}

// a: number[]
const a = [1, 2, 3]
iterate(a) // [1, 2, 3]
iterate(a) // [1, 2, 3]

// b: () => Generator<number>
const b = function*() {
    yield* [1, 2, 3]
}
iterate(b()) // [1, 2, 3]
iterate(b()) // [1, 2, 3]

// c: Generator<number>
const c = b()
iterate(c) // [1, 2, 3]
iterate(c) // []

// d: IterableIterator<number>
const d = [1, 2, 3].values()
iterate(d) // [1, 2, 3]
iterate(d) // []
```

Comment: To a first approximation, you can't. TS doesn't track state changes, and *structurally* there is no (easily encodable) difference between a reusable iterable and a one-time iterable. You could try to simulate such a thing with [branding](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) and [merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) into all appropriate interfaces, possibly as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mxJ61w). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That fully address the qustion. Though, even with branding, it's not possible to differentiate between b() and c, right?

Comment: Yeah I can't think of a good way to do that at all.  Maybe turn all functions that consume a non-reusable iterables into [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) but there's no way to catch all of those.  I think I probably won't suggest branding and just give sources that show TS can't track state changes.  Have to do some research first.

Comment: By the way, even your question isn't asking to distinguish between `b()` and `c`, because neither of them are "reusable".  `b()` isn't reusable, it just hasn't been used yet.  Yes, if you literally write `b()` multiple times you will be getting multiple one-time iterables, but the function should presumably reject those, since a reusable iterable could be iterated multiple times inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript has no good way to distinguish "reusable" [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol) from "one-time" iterables.  TypeScript's type system generally considers types to be stateless.  There's some support for [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) and un-narrowing types based on the control flow of a program, but that support only works in specific circumstances and doesn't track arbitrary mutations.  There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#16148](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16148) to support so-called [*affine types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_type_system#Affine_type_systems) which represent resources that can be used at most once.  If we had affine types in TypeScript then you could possibly encode one-time iterables with an affine type and reuable ones with a normal type.  But we don't have them (and I doubt we ever will).

So this is, to a first approximation, a lost cause.

---

One workaround you can take is to make a type alias for all the types you know to be reusable, and then only accept those:

```
type ReusableIterable =
    ReadonlyArray<any> | ReadonlyMap<any, any> | 
    ReadonlySet<any> | string // | ...

function iterate<T>(iterable: ReusableIterable & Iterable<T>) {
    console.log(Array.from(iterable))
}

const a = [1, 2, 3]
iterate(a) // okay

const b = function* () { yield* [1, 2, 3] }
iterate(b()) // error

const c = b()
iterate(c) // error

const d = [1, 2, 3].values()
iterate(d) // error
```

This necessarily excludes any reusable iterables you don't know about in advance, and also allows any types which conform structurally to one of these but which is only usable once (e.g., a subclass of `Array` that consumes things when you read them). And it definitely can't tell the difference between a "fresh" one-time iterable and a "used" one. But it's probably close to the best you can do.

Note that this is tantamount to saying "just accept `Array` and force callers to use `Array.from()` themselves.  Which isn't great, but at least it has a high likelihood of working.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.1.3#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIBKsCuBnAhgIwDawJLiwBO2e8AvKPDUrBgCYD2AdjpAILGmQA8GLSAD54AHzqNW7ALIZo-QQBp4A4WInM2kAMqxwCteLThiASxYBzeAHpr6gHSPQoAGYoWAY3CnW8U0VIiXgAVIQAKfxIyWAAuOnRowijcBAAyeCTSFJChAEp4AG9qWg9WNCY8exwmCzCuHnsXYiYAWwiA6Nzc0ABfZzAQWxU4lhQWrBIAbQBdUFKWYxVKeEmARmUAJmUAZlmQSMDYMIx8obXNnembOyYAawxIUAOMImPTu3P4Lfhd-qGsOJhfIUEQAcVgLCi4CYxF4o3GJCEczK4HgWGWbk83lYACp4EDCsUaJBTLAcAw8Z9vr8QH19h1Xlgge8VusvpdrvASM1iE8GUcmV1OVTLn87B44uDIYEYXCxhNiEiQPNFh5loK+VCjh4WSKflchtyYZrDmEdcK9qAhgw4plEgzZfCFUqVaiGMs9bt7AA3DA4FCwNBAk0vI4MXVs6kGuxG3n0rVhcMW-pAA)